# Hinge joint rope breaks away when connected platform moves

Tags: unity, 2d, joints, rope-physics

I use hinge joint 2D components to create my rope, and a distance joint to connect it to a moving platform.

On the moving platform I have a distance joint that connects to the first chain joint, so that allows the platform to move, and the rope should follow it.

The problem is that when I move the platform the joint connection will break and joints go crazy. Is there any solution for that?

[image: Rope of hinge jointed circles]

When I move the circle, all the joints go crazy:

[image: Broken rope]

Comment: Do you want a purely visual effect from this rope, or does it need to actually affect the physics movement of the objects it's connected to?

Comment: You need to move it using forces and not directly manipulating its position.  Otherwise you are totally messing up the physics calculations.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was I was moving the platform by its transform, not a rigidbody.

Instead, I found I should use `rigidbody.velocity = dir`  or just `rigidbody.addForce(dir)`

Make sure that max force and max torque are set to infinity for each hinge joint - I'm not sure if this is needed for a distance joint.

Comment: yup with addForce everything works PERFECT !

Comment: You should consider registering. This will allow you to do more stuff on the site here. After that, please go to [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) page to have your accounts merged. You'll be able to comment on your own questions and their answers.

Answer (score 0):

To me it looks like you're using way too many joints for it to work smoothly.

### Anyway, to solve the joint breaking problem...

Take a look at their properties, there's a *max force* and a *max torque* value you can set to *infinity* so it will never break.

Again, this might help with the problem you described, but I'm afraid this might be the wrong direction for most rope animations.